# How to change Magento 2.0.7 root folder name

Tags: magento2, database

I'm trying to change the root folder name of my magento installation ... currently it's 'websitename/project' and i want to change it to 'websitename/store'

I have followed the guidelines to change the URL in database (Core_config_data) and tired to clear cache but every time i do it my website shows without template ... i even tired deleting folders in VAR directory but nothing seems to work ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything in Magento. Just change ut in Apache config file. It's mostly placed at /etc/apache2/site-enabled/yourhostname.conf

Comment: where i can locate apache config file and if you can please elaborate your answer ... Like what steps i need to take?

Comment: @MahibBukhari see extended answer

Comment: cant find this /etc/apache2/site-enabled/yourhostname.conf

Comment: Did you try by running upgrade and compilation command ? However also search for old URL in core_config table if there is any other URL entry you have not changed. Like cookie URL

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that frontend design is not appearing. This may help, please check.

1. Check if enough permissions are there for pub folder
2. Check the missing css and js files with help of browser tools. If they are there in right place then it should be permission issue.
3. Check if htaccess file is there in pub/static folder which has rewrite rule for versioning
4. Check if setup upgrade and static content deploy ran without errors
5. Check if backend is working. If so it is frontend deployment issue.
6. Go through the log files in case errors are there